# HTML file won't find JS and CSS files

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

My page should show a single Google Map.

If I throw the code in a JSFiddle, it works fine.

**All of my files are in the same directory.** I tested in Chrome and Firefox, both don't show the map. So I think there must be something about the way I am calling for access to my  JavaScript and CSS.

### HTML

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bob.css">
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>My Heading</h1>

        <div id="map"></div>

        <p>My paragraph.</p>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="bob.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

### bob.js

```
var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.7831,-122.4039),
    zoom: 12,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
```

---

### bob.css

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

---

### Console output

[image: JavaScript Console]

Comment: Are bob.css and bob.js in the same folder as bob.html?

Comment: @JeremyGallant Yes, they are.

Comment: @Bamgag Filenames are case-sensitive. Did you make sure the files are all written in lowercase, just like in your code?

Comment: @JeremyGallant That is a good thought but my files are, in fact, all lower-case just as they are written in the html file.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the server is (mis)configured in some way so that relative paths don't work. If your files are in the root directory, then an absolute path won't hurt.

Try:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/bob.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/bob.js"></script>
```

Comment: The files are in the same folder. What explanation would justify the use of `/`, everything should be working fine without them anyways.

Comment: Did it work with /? Perhaps the server is (mis)configured in some way so that relative paths don't work. If your files are in the root directory, then an absolute path won't hurt.

Comment: I'm not the OP. But the explanation you just added should be a part of your answer ;-).

Comment: Could you give us the url you are developing on?

Answer (score 0):

I tested both on firefox and chrome, both work smooth.
I assume you are testing this on a site so (as Johan Bouveng said ) there could be something worng, so i would try this instead:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./bob.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="./bob.js"></script>
```

./ to point to the exact same directory of the calling file ( in this case bob.html )